# Knockout - What fires on the element when the bound value changes?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to understand what Knockout does to elements on the page when it updates the values in them due to applyBinding.

Consider this simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Example</title>
        <script src="../lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#itemNumber").change(function() {
                console.log('itemNumber');
            });

            //create The view Model
            var product1 = {
                  id: 1002,
                  itemNumber: "T110",
                  model: "Taylor 110",
                  salePrice: 699.75
                }; 
            ko.applyBindings(product1);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <input data-bind="value: itemNumber" type="text"  id="itemNumber" />
</body>
</html>
```

When i run the page T110 appears in my input box and when i change the value the console message is shown as i expect.

But notice it does not fire when applyBindings is called during the page load as I would expect...

So what mechanism does it use to modify the input element's value? And what i am really looking for is some way to detect this in the element itself as this is a control and I would like to copy the real value from a hidden field to the right place but maintain any values stuck to it...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see for yourself, reading the [source](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings.js#L119) for the *value binding*.

The default event for handling changes is the *change* event but that is [configurable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).

Also, a great way to learn KnockoutJs is to go through the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks, But its not doing what i expect still. Why does the change not fire anytime after: ko.applyBindings(product1); is called? Yet somehow the value is shown... That particular code does not seem to be getting called.

Comment: I have actually been through the tutorials. But i have a case for this specific situation... I think i did find a better way to do it but it does mean my control needs to depend on Knockout which may not always be the case..

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you don't use the change event?

Try manually subscribing to see the effects instead:

```
product1.itemNumber.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But the problem i am interested in is how to detect that ko is changing the value on the object. So when ko.applyBindings is called somehow my value gets updated. How does it do it if the change doesnt fire.

Comment: Do you see both handlers attached (console.log($("#itemNumber").data("events").change.length));)? If not, maybe wrap your code in a $(document).ready() block (I'm grasping), since your script appears before the body.